# What's Spanish for "redeem" in the context of recycling?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico

I most cities, you can recycle ([reciclar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=VR7ahaY)) some of your trash. Sometimes, you can even be given money for it.

When I was a kid in Madrid, there were some places where you could bring used paper (to be recycled) and you would get some money (very little per Kg. of paper or cardboard). We would say that they *bought* the paper from you. This was way before we started to have different trash containers for garbage in order to separate and recycle.

In the United States, you can not only recycle soda cans and other bottles (glass or plastic) but you can *redeem* (redimir?) them.

[image: coke label]

That picture is from a bottle of coke, and basically says that you can get 5 cents back for the plastic bottle in the states of Maine, Vermont, Connecticut, Massachusetts, New York, Hawaii and Iowa, and 10 cents in Oregon and Michigan (and I don't know what the heck they do in California...). It's similar for cans and some glass bottles.

To get that money you may need to take the bottle to a *redemption center* (centro de *redención*?), a liquor store or some other designated places.

Many people take advantage of being able to *redeem* paper, plastic, glass or cans for money. From people who have little to subsist (and benefit from collecting and *redeeming* what is garbage for other people) to others which may collect, *redeem* and then donate the proceedings as they see fit.

I understand that most cities have programs to recycle garbage, but I don't know what they do in order to *redeem* recyclable garbage for money (that is specific of each country, city or state, as seen in the coke label above) or what do they call this action.

As I said at the beginning of the question, a lifetime ago I would had said in Spanish that someone would "*buy* used paper" from you. I understand that not all Spanish speaking towns or cities may offer a *redemption* program from recyclable garbage. The direct translation, [redimir](https://dle.rae.es/?id=VYpI2LB), doesn't seem to be the best in this context.

So, what do you call in Spanish the act of *redeeming* recyclable garbage to get money for it?

Answer (score 3):

Recuerdo que esto ha comenzado a implantarse en España. La palabra que se utiliza es

### Retorno (de envases).

De hecho, si buscamos las acepciones de retornar, hay dos que coinciden:

> 1. tr. devolver (‖ restituir).
>
> [...]
>
> 3. tr. Hacer que algo retroceda o vuelva atrás.

Te recomiendo que busques en Google este término, "retorno de envases", puesto que hay una cantidad de resultados muy prolija.

Destaca que en algunos de los resultados, de hecho, incluye más términos: **depósito, devolución y retorno**. Los tres me parecen también términos muy adecuados.

Finalmente, si también buscas describir el **sobrecoste** inicial del producto, que se **reintegra** con la devolución del envase, no sé si tiene algún término específico, pero lo que mejor me suena es

> **Fianza**
>
> 1. f. Cantidad de dinero o bien material que se entrega como garantía del cumplimiento de una obligación.

Comment: Just realized the question was actually in English. Tell me if you want the translation.

Comment: Por lo que tengo entendido, se **retorna** el envase (salvo los _no retornables_) y se **devuelve** el depósito.

Comment: Seguramente. Puedes ver que no estoy muy puesto en el tema, desgraciadamente, porque aún no ha llegado a mi ciudad. Pero bueno, reciclo y casi no tiro nada.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. No hace falta publicar en inglés (suelo intentar promover el español, pero con esta me dio por publicar en inglés, a ver si se colaba en las Hot Network Questions). A mi también me confunden los términos, porque uno devuelve la lata, pero a él le devuelven dinero... Supongo que "devolución" en lo que mejor encaja para la acción de retornar un envase y recibir la _finaza_ del _sobrecoste_...

Answer (score 3):

En el contexto Mexicano tanto como el Estadounidense, donde existen centros de reciclaje donde uno puede llevar sus envases reciclables, esto se puede llamar un ***[canje](https://dle.rae.es/?id=79bSYhL)***.

> Hay lugares adonde se llevan los envases y se **canjean** por dinero.

Otra palabra que podría llenar este requisito sería la palabra que es un poco más común, que sería ***[intercambio](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Lsc0igT)***.

> Hay lugares adonde se llevan los envases y se **intercambian** por dinero.

Igual se puede decir que se compra el reciclable, y entonces vas a vender tus envases. Esto resulta ser la forma más sencilla de expresar esta idea, a pesar de que en realidad no es una venta, pero se presta la situación para llamarse ***venta***, por igual.

Comment: En España también usamos *canjear*. Para mí, es la mejor traducción de *redeem* y se puede usar igualmente en otros contextos.

Answer (score 1):

Una de las acepciones de *[redeem](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/redeem)* es:

> Gain or regain possession of (something) in exchange for payment.

Y en este sentido una de las traducciones que propone Google Translator es *rescate*. Como si te hubieran cobrado 5 centavos más por la botella y luego tuvieras que ir a rescatarlos entregando la botella a cambio. En este sentido se me hace más natural el verbo *reclamar* como posible traducción: entregas la botella para reclamar el dinero que te corresponde.

En todo caso, recuerdo cuando de pequeño llevaba las botellas de vidrio vacías a los supermercados, donde te daban un poco de dinero por ellas (antes de que llegara el plástico o los contenedores de reciclaje). No recuerdo usar ningún verbo especial, creo que directamente hablaba de llevar las botellas a reciclar al súper, o simplemente de *devolver* las botellas, y eso ya implicaba el hecho de que me iba a llevar un dinerito a cambio.

Comment: Te pasa igual que a mi entonces. Hace 20-20 años lo mismo podrías haber dicho que te las "recompraban" o algo similar (y se entendería que te recompraban la botella de vidrio _vacía_). Ahora, que lo de separar y reciclar ya es una acción cotidiana, no sé si tiene un nombre un nombre específico esa acción de reclamar ese sobrecoste o impuesto adicional (que supongo que está ahí para obligarte o estimularte a reciclar).

Answer (score 1):

Por curiosidad y completitud de la pregunta, me ha dado por mirar lo que es ese "CA CRV" y resulta que es:

> California Redemption Value (CRV), also known as California Refund Value, is a regulatory fee paid on recyclable beverage containers in California.
>
> Fuente: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_Redemption_Value)

La entrada explica un poco más sobre esa tasa

> The bottler pays CRV for beverages with aluminum, plastic, glass, and bimetal containers and anyone can receive the same amount in exchange for the container by bringing it to a recycling center. The symbol on beverage containers eligible for **reimbursement** is "CA CRV"

Es decir "El símibolo en aquello contenedores de bebidas elegibles para el **reembolso** es CA CRV".

No sé por qué no se me ocurrió "reembolso" antes, pero sería otra buena opción a añadir a las ya aportadas, ya que su significado no es más que "devolver una cantidad a poder de quien la había desembolsado previamente", que en este caso entiendo que es el fabricante, que traslada al consumidor cuando compra la botella y que devuelve (reembolsa) al retornarla.

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is "canjear" which means get a reward for something, which is the most near word to redeem